# Loop and Insert PHP multi-dimensional array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, task

I have a multi-dimensional array in php 
that look like this :

```
 Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 0
        [periods] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 01:00
                        [1] => 01:30
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 02:30
                        [1] => 03:00
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 1
        [periods] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 01:30
                        [1] => 02:00
                    )

            )

    )
```

The "day" key reffer to the day so day[0] = "monday"
And the "periods" key reffer to the hour that the user has selected on the same day.

So in the day[0] there is a 'periods' array that reffer to anthor array that store the hour , start 01:00, end 01:30 start 02:30, end 03:00

I try to foreach loop this array but I can not find a way.
I want to enter this value for each hour to mysql like so:

```
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO task_list (
            task, day, hour
            ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ";
```

ex : day: 0 start 1:00 , day: 0 end 1:30

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your Solution....

```
$array = array(
        array(
            'day' => 0,
            'periods' => array(
                array('01:00','01:30'),
                array('02:00','03:00'),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'day' => 1,
            'periods' => array(
                array('01:00','02:00')
            )
        )
    );

   //echo "<pre>";print_r($array);

   $values = '"INSERT INTO task_list ( task, day, hour ) VALUES';
   foreach($array as $row){
        foreach($row['periods'] as $row1){
                $values .= '("start","'.$row['day'].'","'.$row1[0].'"),("end","'.$row['day'].'","'.$row1[1].'"),';
        }
   }
   $values .= ';"';
   $values = str_replace(',;',';',$values);
   echo $values;
```

Comment: Is there a way to restore the array with the same construction after I retrieve the data from mysql?

Comment: Hi Gyandeep, im trying to convert to result form my SQL query to the array format, but i still not found a way. i do a foreach and the best i get is to separate array fro the same day

Comment: Sure i will add this

Comment: if ($result) {
  
 $k = 0;
 
  foreach ($result as $i => $row) {
    
   $data[$i]["day"]      = $row["day"];
   $data[$i]["periods"][$k] = array();
   
   array_push($data[$i]["periods"][$k], $row["start_hour"], $row["stop_hour"]);
   $k ++;  
  }
  
 $row_set = $data;
 
 return $row_set;
 
 }